# Linear combination of two Brownian bridges

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

(I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem $3.1$ in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aap/1300198521).)

Denote by $B^{(x)}(t)$ a Brownian bridge process which starts at $0$ at time $0$ and ends at $x$ at time $t$, i.e.

\begin{equation}
B^{(x)}(t) = B(t) - t(B(1) - x),
\end{equation}

where $B(\cdot)$ is a standard Brownian motion.

I am interested in

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P} \bigl( \,\inf_{0 \le t \le 1} \{ c_1 B_1(t) + c_2 B_2(1 - t)\} \le x \mid B_1(1) = b_1, B_2(1) = b_2 \bigr), \tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $B_1(\cdot)$ and $B_2(\cdot)$ are two independent standard Brownian motions. By conditioning on the event, $B_1(\cdot)$ and $B_2(\cdot)$ essentially become two Brownian bridge processes. Consider the case that $x \le \min(b_1c_1,b_2c_2)$, then, with some abuse of notation, we have

\begin{equation}
(1) = \mathbb{P} \bigl( \, \inf_{0 \le t \le 1} \{ c_1 B_1^{(b_1)}(t) + c_2 B_2^{(b_2)}(1-t)\} \le x \bigr), \tag{2}
\end{equation}

where we can simplify

\begin{align}
B_2^{(b_2)}(1-t) &= B(1 - t) - (1 - t)(B(1) - b_2) \\
&= B(1 - t) - B(1) + tB(1) + b_2 - tb_2 \\
&= - \bigl( B(t) - t(B(1) - b_2) \bigr) + b_2 \\
&= - B_2^{(b_2)}(t) + b_2
\end{align}

since $B(1) - B(1 - t)$ is again a Brownian motion (at time $t$). Plugging this back in $(2)$ we obtain

\begin{equation}
(2) = \mathbb{P} \bigl( \, \inf_{0 \le t \le 1} \{ b_2 c_2 + c_1 B_1^{(b_1)}(t) - c_2 B_2^{(b_2)}(t)\} \le x \bigr), \tag{3}
\end{equation}

which, according to the paper, is equal to

\begin{equation}
(3) = \mathbb{P} \bigl( \, \inf_{0 \le t \le 1} \{ b_2 c_2 + \sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2} B^{(\frac{b_1 c_1 - b_2 c_2}{\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2}})}(t)\} \le x \bigr).
\end{equation}

How does the last equality follow and is the rest correct as well?

Comment: Hint: what is the sum of two Brownian motions ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom Not a Brownian motion, unless you scale them. If I recall correctly, 

\begin{equation}
B_3(t) = \frac{aB_1(t) + b B_2(t)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}
\end{equation}

is a Brownian motion. So, that explains the scaling by $\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2}$, but what about the value at time $t = 1$?

Comment: So you've got the answer !

Comment: @Tom-Tom So, in general the following holds?

\begin{equation}
B^{(\frac{ax + by}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}})}(t) = \frac{a B_1^{(x)}(t) + b B_2^{(y)}(t)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}
\end{equation}

Comment: I think you can prove it ! Check the position at $t=1$.

Comment: I see that the position at time $t = 1$ for $c_1 B^{(b_1)}(t) - c_2 B^{(b_2)}(t)$ is just $b_1c_2 - b_2c_2$. This seems much easier than I expected. Thanks!